# Maven iPojo plugin with jdk16

Tags: maven

i'm working on an OSGi project built with maven on a jdk1.7. the pom contanin maven-ipojo-plugin. i have migrate the project on an environment with jdk16 and i'm having a great trouble: maven-ipojo-plugin doesn't work when i build the projec with maven and e get the following error:

```
'''
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle (default) on project mdp-common-osgi-bundle: Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle (default) on project mdp-common-osgi-bundle: Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider.computeAnnotations (AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:109)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider.access$200 (AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:44)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider$1.visit (AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:90)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.store.JarFileResourceStore.accept (JarFileResourceStore.java:161)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider.getMetadatas (AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.CompositeMetadataProvider.getMetadatas (CompositeMetadataProvider.java:53)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.Pojoization.pojoization (Pojoization.java:360)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.Pojoization.pojoization (Pojoization.java:243)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.plugin.ManipulatorMojo.execute (ManipulatorMojo.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
'''
```

and the plugins are:

```
'''
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ipojo-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>ipojo-bundle</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>6.0_BETA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
'''

'''
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>16</release>
        <testRelease>16</testRelease>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
            <artifactId>doxia-module-markdown</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
'''
```

someone has resolved this trouble or knows how can it be resolved???

thank you

Comment: Does this example here help? - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FELIX/iPOJO+Maven+Plug-in

Answer (score 0):

The output shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetada
```

That means the plugin is not ready to run with JDK16+ adding a dependency to asm does not help here because it looks like the plugins needs to be fixed...but based on this: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.felix%20AND%20a:maven-ipojo-plugin

it looks like the plugin is not maintained any more and I strongly recommend to search for an alternative... Also I would suggest to upgrade to at least JDK 17 instead of JDK 16 (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html)

Adding a dependency (markdown?) to the maven-compiler-plugin is simply wrong because the maven-compiler-plugin compiles code but does not generate any html output or parses markdown files...

Comment: do you know what could it be an alternative? how can it be possible make something that a plugin does?

Comment: I would suggest to check this: https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html